# How to encrypt files on iPhone when user does not have a passcode set?

Tags: iphone, ios

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW11) and other documentation I have read about on disk encryption on an iOS device, it seems that in order to take advantage of the advanced encryption of the device the user must have a passcode enabled so that when you use the NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete attribute it will encrypt.

What if the user does not have a passcode set but I still want to ensure the files are encrypted? What options are there for this scenario?

Thanks!
Flea

Comment: You can encrypt the file with your own encryption algorithm.

Comment: @H2CO3, I'd like to give you the benefit of the doubt, because English might not be your first language.  But, suggesting that a developer write their own *algorithm* is **terrible** advice.  Many people whose careers have been spent in encryption have written many good algorithms that should be chosen over a roll-your-own implementation.  If you are simply suggesting that Flea use one of these choices, for example, with his own key or salt, that's fine.  But, typically that's not what's meant by the phrase *encryption algorithm* - so if that's what you meant, I'd recommend different wording.

Comment: @Nate Thanks, as you guessed, English is not my native language. However, I know the difference between "my own algorithm" and "someone else's algorithm compiled by me". I was actually suggesting this because in some cases it might be useful to come up with something completely uncommon in order to make reverse engineers' work harder. Of course, there are good encryption algorithms out there, but, in a really few cases, I think you have the right of inventing something new. Imagine what would have happened if all those people who invented these *algorithms* had been told that

Comment: "coming up with your own implementation is bad practice"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS [includes several APIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172-CH9-SW14) for encrypting data. The automatic on-disk encryption is a user-selected option that lets the user encrypt all the data written to the device's secondary storage. If you need your data to be encrypted whether or not the user chooses to turn on that option, encrypt the data yourself using one of the options provided.

Unless you *really* know what you're doing (and even if you *think* you do, you probably don't), it's generally a better idea to use the provided APIs which you can expect to have been written and reviewed by experts.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, so it sounds like if I don't trust the user, which I don't, I should implement Certificate, Key, and Trust Services API or the CommonCrypto API.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to distribute your app outside the US, and you use encryption, you will have to comply with the US Bureau of Commerce restrictions.  If you use Apple's provided APIs and you are only using encryption to protect your content, you will be able to distribute your app internationally (according to Apple's iTunesConnect FAQ.)

However, if you write the encryption yourself you will have to go through a review process with the US government.

I've written more than one app that encrypts content on a server so it can be protected even after it has been downloaded to the device.

Even Apple's encryption doesn't prevent someone from making an unencrypted backup or mounting the device as a filesystem and taking the media files your app might have downloaded.

So, to protect your content you must encrypt it yourself.  And, you must only decrypt it in ram and never as a temporary file in flash memory (which could be copied off the device.)  This makes serving encrypted movies and PDFs a bit challenging.  I use a decrypting web server thread; however, there are more modern approaches including a file-level delegate approach that might work better.